# What should I look for when shopping for a kitchen faucet water filter?

Tags: water, filter

I'm looking for a kitchen faucet water filter that I can install, and found several online.  My main goal is to have easy access to clean water in my apartment, and to also have a method of filling 5 gallon bottles to replace my Sparkletts delivery service.

When looking for a kitchen water filtration system, what are the main things that one should look for?  I'm also looking for one that has a large tank to support a 5-gallon fill up.

Answer (score 2):

The first question to ask is what you want to filter out and why. From the wording of your question, it appears that you think your drinking water is unclean. As far as I know, public drinking water is safe everywhere in the United States, so I'll assume that you have well water. If so, you need to start by having the water tested. Use a local or semi-local lab, as they will know what to test for in your area. The staff of nearby public water districts can probably recommend a reputable, local lab.

Depending on the test results, there are different kinds of filters. If your water is very hard, some filters will require that you also have a water softener.

If you are just looking to improve the taste of safe water, then a carbon filter will likely suffice. They can be mounted on the tap; alternatively, a whole-house filter can be installed for a few hundred dollars. (That may not be an option for an apartment dweller.)

Comment: As Vebjorn mentioned depends what your trying to get out, but as far as minor impurities such as metals and dirt etc with a large flow rate I'd go the whole house filter eg a dual pod 20" cartage setup with sediment and carbon filters. But if its Bacteria etc definatly  check ur water at a lab